# how to save typing in c++

Tags: c++, macros

I have a piece of code like this I need to put in front of a lot of functions.

```
#ifdef __AA__
    __BB__ __CC__
#endif
```

But it's just too trivial to write it every time and it makes code looks ugly.

Is there any way I can define something like macro to make it short? Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: Do note the names with double underscores are reserved for the C++ implementation and are illegal for you to use.

Comment: *"Is there any way I can define something like macro to make it short? Thanks."* -- No. You are telling the compiler what code to *conditionally* include in your program. There is no shortcut to cut the 2-line conditional (`#ifdef ... #endif`) down to something shorter. (and yes, it can look awkward -- but the the compiler doesn't care about looks `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a preprocessor macro conditionally:

```
#ifdef __AA__
# define FN_INTRO __BB__ __CC__
#else
# define FN_INTRO
#endif
```

Then before each function you can just write `FN_INTRO` instead of the whole thing.

Comment: Perfect! I have verified your code works! Thanks you very much!